# Prolog sum of acalculation

Tags: prolog

I have some cartesian coordinates definition:

```
point(a, 5, 1).
point(b, 4, 2).
point(c, 3, 3).
point(d, 2, 4).
```

And a "route" definition:

```
route(path1, [a, c, b, d]).
```

Then I have a function to calculate the distance between two points, like this:

```
distance(P1, P2, D):-point(P1, X1, Y1), point(P2, X2, Y2),
 Z is ((X2-X1)*(X2-X1))+((Y1-Y2)*(Y1-Y2)),
 Z >= 0,
 D is sqrt(Z).
```

How can I calculate the full distance of a route?

Also, if I have several routes how can I find the longest one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: should be correct now**

First, to find the length of a given route, using the distance function you have provided:

```
path_len(Path, D) :- route(Path, [First|Points]), path_len(Points, First, 0, D).

path_len([], _Last, Dist, Dist).
path_len([P|Points], Prev, DAcc, Dist) :-
    distance(Prev, P, D),
    NDAcc is DAcc+D,
    path_len(Points, P, NDAcc, Dist).
```

where *DAcc* is an accumulator for the distance so far (initialized with 0). You can query this with

```
?- path_len(path1, D).
```

If you have several routes defined already (do I understand this correctly?), `path_len/2` will calculate the total distance of all of them by backtracking. You can then build distance-path pairs and use `keysort/2` to sort them and maybe `reverse/2` to put the last one first:

```
longest_path(Path, Dist) :-
    bagof(D-P, path_len(P, D), DPPairs),
    keysort(DPPairs, Sorted),
    reverse(Sorted, [Dist-Path|_]).
```

You could have also used `last/2` instead of `reverse/2` on the last line of the predicate definition:

```
last(Sorted, Dist-Path).
```

Comment: Hi Boris, thank you for your time. I'm getting "false" as a result from the path_len function. Any thoughts?

Comment: @pvl You're welcome. Please note and use in the future the unpacking of arguments done between `path_len/2` and `path_len/4`. It is a very useful idiom for working with pairs of consecutive elements in a list.